# ggplot2 facet_wrap results in blank queries

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been using ggplot2 to create geom_point graphs, and it works:

```
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(
  X = sample(1:10),
  Y = sample(1:10),
  Z = sample(c("Up", "Down", "Left", "Right"), 10, replace = TRUE))

e <- ggplot(data, aes(x = X, y = Y, colour = Z))
e + geom_point()
```

However, when I try to use faceting it results in a blank graph:

```
e + facet_wrap(. ~ Z)
```

And I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add the point layer.

```
e + geom_point() + facet_wrap(. ~ Z)

# same as
# e <- ggplot(data, aes(x = X, y = Y, colour = Z)) + geom_point()
# e + facet_wrap(. ~ Z)
```

[image]